# Can I access elements in react native web view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am displaying a url in my app I want to check if the page contains a given word let say that the url is

> https://github.com/facebook/react-native

how can I say to my app If any link contains the word facebook hide or remove that entire html element.

that's how I am displaying the link :

```
 <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to access the elements inside WebView. You can directly hide/show the WebView component. Define the link as a string:

```
const myLink = 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native';
```

Then, you can check if it contains the word facebook. If it contains it, you can show or hide it like this;

```
{ myLink.indexOf('facebook') > -1 ? 
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
        /> : null 
}
```

You can also inject JavaScript rules into your WebView. For this, you'll need the following props on your component:

```
    <WebView
      javaScriptEnabled
      injectedJavaScript={'function injectRules() {' + myRule + '};injectRules();'}
      source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
    />
```

This basically defines a JavaScript function and invokes it. Then you'll need to implement the function as a string on react-native side. Following is just an example that changes color, you can implement your own JS function that hides an element:

```
const myRule = 'document.querySelector("div>p").style.color ="black";';
```

You can further wrap it in an if condition:

```
const myRule = myLink.indexOf('facebook') > -1 ? 'document.querySelector("div>p").style.color ="black";' : 'return;';
```

Comment: Thanks Faruk for your response but that will hide the entire page I want null to be affected to only that <a href="" or parent div

Comment: @salmanaacvf I edited my answer and added the methods to access WebView elements, you can check it.